# eclipselink maven repository not working

Tags: maven, eclipselink, pom.xml

I am getting this error:

The POM for org.eclipse.persistence:eclipselink:jar:2.3.2 is missing, no dependency information available
The POM for org.eclipse.persistence:javax.persistence:jar:2.0.3 is missing, no dependency information available

When I go to http://download.eclipse.org/rt/eclipselink/maven.repo/ shows no files and other pages throw 404.

I seem not to be able to find a solution. I use Netbeans. Any solutions?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try the pom.xml sample at http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Maven? It works for me.

Comment: Yes, I have tried that! It was working for me till few days ago now it is not working!!

Comment: The http link is always going to show a 404, even when the repo is working.

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe your jar became corrupted in your local repository.

Go to ~/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/persistence and try deleting that folder structure, this will force maven to re-download.

Also try running:

```
mvn install -U
```

If that doesn't work, then purge your repo:

```
mvn dependency:purge-local-repository
```

Also try building from command line, because sometimes IDES will not rebuild the Maven Index, until you restart it.